# Проблемы с инициализацией двумерного массива в чистом С

Tags: c, массивы, двумерный-массив

Есть двумерный массив:

```
double ** distance_matrix = create_matrix(4);
```

Есть функция, создающая его:

```
double ** create_matrix(size_t matrix_size)
{
  double ** matrix;  
  
  matrix = (double **)malloc(sizeof(matrix) * matrix_size);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < matrix_size; ++i)
    {
      matrix[i] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(matrix[i]) * matrix_size);      
    }
  return matrix; 
}
```

И, самое главное, есть функция, его заполняющая:

```
void init_distance_matrix(double *** matrix, int matrix_size)
{
  double ** distance_matrix = *(matrix);
  
  distance_matrix[0][0] = 0;
  distance_matrix[0][1] = -1;
  distance_matrix[0][2] = 7;
  distance_matrix[0][3] = 25;
  //printf("ok\n");
  distance_matrix[1][0] = 18;
  distance_matrix[1][1] = 0;
  distance_matrix[1][2] = 4;
  distance_matrix[1][3] = 3;

  distance_matrix[2][0] = -1;
  distance_matrix[2][1] = 5;
  distance_matrix[2][2] = 0;
  distance_matrix[2][3] = 27;

  distance_matrix[3][0] = -1;
  distance_matrix[3][1] = 8;
  distance_matrix[3][2] = 94;
  distance_matrix[3][3] = 0;
}
```

Проблема в том, что когда `printf("ok\n")` раскоментирована, то все работает. Но стоит ее закоментировать, и программа падает на этой функции.

Comment: При таких симптомах ошибка может оказаться где-то в совершенно ином месте. Портится память. Есть [минимальный компилируемый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Это не двухмерный массив, а массив с указателями. Размеры, указанные при вызовах `malloc`, неверные. Делайте одномерный массив с `matrix_size * matrix_size` элементами. Еще http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer

Comment: Покажите вызов `init_distance_matrix`.

Comment: У Вас, как минимум, ошибка в строке `matrix[i] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(matrix[i]) * matrix_size);`. Там по сути должно стоять `matrix[i] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * matrix_size);`, а Вы туда скармливаете размер **указателя на double**. На 64-битной архитектуре (когда размер указателя и типа double по 8 байт) эта ошибка может быть незаметна... Но вот при 32-битной архитектуре получится, что размер каждого элемента в 2 раза меньше (ну или элементов будет в итоге в 2 раза меньше и Вы вылезете за выделенную память).

Comment: То же самое (неверное указание объекта для sizeof) касается строки `matrix = (double **)malloc(sizeof(matrix) * matrix_size);`, но тут размер указателя и указателя на указатель отличаться не будет, и потому все пройдет без видимых проблем.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы выделяете память используя неправильные типы. Сначала массив для указателей :

```c
matrix = (double **)malloc(sizeof(matrix) * matrix_size);
// тип matrix == double * *
```

потом опять массив указателей :

```c
matrix[i] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(matrix[i]) * matrix_size);
// тип matrix[i] == double *
```

А в массиве должны были быть не указатели, а числа типа **double**.

Можно указывать типы других элементов :

```c
matrix = (double **)malloc(sizeof(matrix[0]) * matrix_size);
// тип matrix[0] == double *
```

```c
matrix[i] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(matrix[i][0]) * matrix_size);
// тип matrix[i][0] == double
```

или же явно указывать типы :

```c
matrix = (double **)malloc(sizeof(double*) * matrix_size);
```

```c
matrix[i] = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * matrix_size);
```

---

*Так как типы `double` и указатели обычно имеют один размер 8 байт, то эта проблема несоответствия типов в вашем коде могла не  играть роль. И настоящая проблема может находится в другом участке кода.*